# JIRA Ticket Best Practices: How to write a good JIRA ticket

Tags: standards, jira, technical-writing

We "use" JIRA as our ticketing system, but "use" is a real stretch. We have no standards, no templates, no "best practices" documentation for writing a proper JIRA ticket. So I'm spearheading the movement to create such a doc.

It's bad. Real bad. Sometimes, the reporter just copies-n-pastes a stacktrace and submits the ticket without providing any context, backstory, or directions to reproduce.

I was wondering if anybody had some good input for what format/template we could use and enforce so that I never get a lousily-written ticket assigned to me ever again! Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000029.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic information needed in any error report:

- What exactly did you do?
- What exactly did you expect to happen?
- What exactly happened instead?

There's a bunch of other information that can be crucial, but depends on the specifics of the system and your environment - things like what user account was used, what domain objects were being worked on, what server the error occurred on, etc.

But also be careful that your effort to increase ticket quality does not end up discouraging people from submitting tickets at all - that's what happens when you cram everything you can think of into a template and force people to fill out all fields even when most of them don't apply to every ticket.